# urequests only working on specific websites

Tags: api, request, microcontroller, http-status-codes, micropython

I am using a nodemcu esp8266 and the plan is to make a spotify api request to automate playing some songs, and I have a fully functional python script that does exactly that, but when I tried to convert it to upython it failed. I have now spent hours on this and have figured out that the problem is that the urequest for some reason only works on specific websites, for example if I try:

```
import urequests as requests

x = requests.get('https://www.spotify.com')
print(x.status_code)
```

i get a 302

but when I try:

```
import urequests as requests

x = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
print(x.status_code)
```

I get a 200. That problem percists with a few websites and with no valid response my urequests.put command does not return the things I need... any ideas how to fix it?
thank you in advance.

this is the code I am trying to run:

```
import urequests as requests
import ujson as json 

refresh_token = "xxxxx"
base_64 = "xxxxx"


class Refresh:

def __init__(self):
    self.refresh_token = refresh_token
    self.base_64 = base_64

def refresh(self):

    query = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    
    payload={"grant_type": "refresh_token", "refresh_token": refresh_token}
    headers={'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base_64}
    data = (json.dumps(payload)).encode()
    
    response = requests.post(query,
                              data=data,
                              headers=headers)


    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.reason)

a = Refresh()
a.refresh()
```

Comment: That's not a problem with `urequests`. That's how the websites work. E.g., try `curl -i https://www.spotify.com`; that sends a redirect (if you're in the US) to `https://www.spotify.com/us/`. What you're seeing is the expected behavior of the website you're trying to access.

Comment: but I have the exact same code in normal python with the normal request function and that works perfectly fine. plus that problem is for a microcontroller and as far as I can tell it only has micropython installed and not curl

Comment: The normal `requests` module follows redirects by default. `urequests` does not; you would need to parse the 302 response and extract the `Location` header yourself. I was not suggesting running `curl` on the microcontroller; I was suggesting that running on your host to demonstrate to yourself that `urequests` is accurately presenting the response from the website.

Comment: ohhhh thats what you mean.. well when I run curl it redirects me to https://www.spotify.com/at/, the only problem is I have already tried putting that address into the urequests and it gives me a status code 500. If I am missing something I am really sorry, I have been searching for a solution for so many hours now and I am exhausted... plus I am still kinda new to working with requests so im sorry I you have to spell out something obvious

Comment: The content at `https://www.spotify.com/at/` is over 62k; I suspect you're running into a memory error on the esp8266. But if you'll be using the [spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/), you wouldn't be connecting to `https://www.spotify.com/at/` and reading that content; you would be connecting to the API endpoint `https://api.spotify.com/v1`.

Comment: yes wow that was exactly what was happening, I tried the new adress and ran into a 400 bad request error message and the same with the api.spotify so apparently it was a problem with my request after all.. I tried so many different versions and thought I had fixed that problem but apparently i never found the correct solution.. I edited the question to provide the token request code I am trying to run, could you please tell me what I have to fix to get it to work? Thank you so much for your answers so far, they have helped me so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on here that are going to cause your problems.

First, you're trying to send JSON data to the `/api/token` endpoint:

```
    data = (json.dumps(payload)).encode()
    
    response = requests.post(query,
                              data=data,
                              headers=headers)
```

...but according to [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/), this endpoint excepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Second, while the documentation suggests you need to send a basic`Authorization` header, in my experiments this evening I wasn't able to get that to work...but I *was* able to successfully refresh a token if I included the client id and secret in the request body.

You can see my forum post with this question [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/Errors-in-authorization-code-flow-documentation-for-refreshing/m-p/5386917).

With that in mind, the following code seems to work on my esp8266 running micropython 1.18:

```
import urequests as requests

refresh_token = "..."
client_id = "..."
client_secret = "..."


class Refresh:
    def __init__(self, refresh_token, client_id, client_secret):
        self.refresh_token = refresh_token
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

    def refresh(self):
        url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
        data = "&".join(
            [
                "grant_type=refresh_token",
                f"refresh_token={self.refresh_token}",
                f"client_id={self.client_id}",
                f"client_secret={self.client_secret}",
            ]
        )

        headers = {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }

        response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

        print(data)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.reason)
        print(response.text)


a = Refresh(refresh_token, client_id, client_secret)
a.refresh()
```